# Why does this code sequence give me an error 102

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

anybody an idea why this gives me an error 102, wrong syntax?

```
declare @i int=20

while @i<=50
begin
    try
        if convert(char,getdate(),@i) is not null 
            begin
                select convert(char,getdate(),@i) 
            end
        set @i=@i+1
    end try
    begin catch
        set @i=@i+1
    end catch;
end
```

Comment: Also, when using `convert`, you should **always** specify an explicit **length** for your target variable. Otherwise you might end up with a nasty surprise and a variable of 1 character length....

Comment: does the target variable (in this case char) sometimes not get the default length 30? how and when is that? how can it end up with length 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your indentation, I believe you wanted `BEGIN TRY` for line 5.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi colon after end catch, and add begin before the try.

Something like

```
declare @i int=20

while @i<=50
begin
    begin try
        if convert(char,getdate(),@i) is not null 
            begin
                select convert(char,getdate(),@i) 
            end
        set @i=@i+1
    end try
    begin catch
        set @i=@i+1
    end catch
end
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19495)

Here is the [corrected Syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `begin try`, not just `try`, so the `begin` before the `try` will be associated with the `try`. That means that the `catch` ends up outside the `while`, separated from the `try`, and you end up with one too many `end` statements at the end.

So, just change `try` to `begin try`.